MongoDB Change Stream Triggered by updatedAt Field Only: How to Handle?
I'm using MongoDB change streams with Mongoose to monitor changes in my Instances collection. Here is the code I'm working with:
Instances.watch(watchFilter, { 
 fullDocument: "updateLookup", 
  fullDocumentBeforeChange: "whenAvailable" 
}).on("change", (data) => {
  if (data.operationType === "update" && data.fullDocumentBeforeChange) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});

The issue I'm encountering is that the change stream event is being triggered even when only the updatedAt field is modified. It doesn't make sense to me because I would expect other fields to be updated as well, not just the updatedAt field.
Example data returned:
{
    ns: { db: 'main', coll: 'instances' },
    documentKey: { _id: new ObjectId("63cf3229cbc4eeec96cac47b") },
    updateDescription: {
        updatedFields: { updatedAt: 2024-08-29T06:28:52.503Z },
        removedFields: [],
        truncatedArrays: []
    },
    fullDocumentBeforeChange: ...,
    fullDocument: ...
}

Why is this happening, and how can I configure my change stream to ignore these updates if only the updatedAt field is modified?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
